# How can I solve this kind of equation in Maple?

Tags: equation, maple

equation1:

```
solve({a^2+b^2+169+sqrt(c-13)-24*a-10*b = 0},{a, b, c}) 
  assuming a>0, b>0, c>0;
//a=12, b=5, c=13
```

equation2:

```
solve([1/(cos(a)^2)+1/(sin(a)^2*sin(b)^2*cos(b)^2) = 9, 
 a>0, a<Pi/2, b>0, b<Pi/2], [a,b,c] );
 //a=arctan(sqrt(2)), b=Pi/4
```

I have tired above, but maple couldn't gives a solutions,  Am I using solve incorrectly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because has nothing to do with programming. You could have more luck on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

In (Eq. 1) it's not your syntax that's an issue. You have three unknowns {a,b,c} but only one equation. You simply do not have enough equations to determine {a,b,c} uniquely. Maple's `solve` function only returns an answer (if possible) if the number of variables equals the number of equations.

In (Eq. 2) you use square brackets, which are used for ordered lists. The `solve` function requires a set of equations, which are indicated by curly braces. Again, you have three variables but only one equation. Same problem.

If the equations are linear (which they aren't in your case), Maple can find a parameterization for the solutions in the case of an underdetermined system: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=solve/linear.